# How to switch branch using `git`?

Tags: git, egit

When I do `git checkout <branchname>` git says, that
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting

Is it possible to do automatic merging? Doing `git stash` does not work for me as sometimes `git stash pop` fails! So I am afraid of it and so manually collecting the changes, removing the changes and applying after switching the branch, this takes a lot of time

Comment: when you say git stash does not work for me, do you get error messages when you try to use this command? if so, what are they?

Comment: git stash is for when you want to save current state of working directory and the staging area, and want to return to a clean working directory. The command saves your local changes & reverts working directory. Have you read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash ?

Comment: @mike, it seems, when it does not work, I am using Eclipse, looks like it is a bug of git used by Eclipse.

Comment: Is this the issue you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366266/switch-to-another-branch-in-egit-cannot-work ?

Comment: How many files does git says as local changes when you try to switch branch? When it's few files and you can **redo** the changes, then you try git checkout <file_name(s)_with_path>. Eg: git checkout pom.xml this will **replace"* all your local changes with whatever branch you're in currently.  Please take backup or think before you replace it.

Comment: Otherwise, when you want to push your local changes, please use git add <file(s)> then git commit -m "<COMMIT MESSAGE>" then git push origin <BRANCH NAME> to push your local changes to branch. Later, you can switch to another branch

Answer (score 0):

You have options in this scenario and I'll explain them to help you choose one.

Option 1: [Stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

```
git stash
```

You have already said this doesn't work for you, but maybe a good way to think about it is that stash is for code that you wouldn't mind forgetting about. If it's the type of changes that you wouldn't care about losing it's easy to throw in the stash directory and forget about them.

Option 2: [Commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

```
git add <whatever>
git commit -m "<whatever>"
```

It is often easier to unstage your changes with a [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) like `git reset --soft <commit hash before the changes>` then to try and remember what you did and didn't stash or why stash isn't working.

After either run a

```
git status
git log
git stash list
```

To make sure you've got your changes where you want them before checking out another branch.

Comment: typically, the changes I have in the worktree are the changes I need in the new branch, so if I commit them before switching, then I will need to apply that commit to a new branch, seems.